# Added spring-boot-configuration-processor as recommended, but produced NoClassDefFoundError in RoundDispatcher

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I'm working on a SpringBoot project, and I just converted it from SpringBoot 1.5 to 2.  I noticed that a config class bean method (for my DataSource) with a @ConfigurarationProperties annotation had a warning that said this:

> When using @ConfigurationProperties it is recommended to add 'spring-boot-configuration-processor' to your 
>    classpath to generate configuration metadata

So I added that artifact to the POM, and that removed the warning, but I'm not sure what the benefit is.  I read the appendix that talked about "Configuration Metadata", and I'm still not sure what the point is.

Even worse, I discovered that although this change presented no issues building and testing the app on my desktop, when I ran the build on our Linux CI server, it failed with the following:

> [ERROR] .../package-info.java: 
>   1. ERROR in .../package-info.java (at line 0)
>       /**
>       ^
>   Internal compiler error: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/metadata/JsonMarshaller at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.handleProcessor(RoundDispatcher.java:172)
>   [ERROR] Found 1 error and 1 warning.

I then commented out the artifact reference, which brought back the warning and fixed my CI build.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

What's going on:

You're using groovy-eclipse-batch/groovy-eclipse-compiler to build and are hitting a bug in the eclipse compiler. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=530665 shows the root cause. It's marked fixed in Eclipse compiler 4.8 RC2. Unfortunately, in my own investigation of the same problem I haven't been able to figure out which version of the eclipse compiler is used in the groovy-eclipse maven artifacts (nor even which one should be changed in order to select a given version!)

Sorry this isn't very helpful right now. I haven't yet been able to get it working even with the latest of both groovy-eclipse artifacts.

If it's possible to migrate your build to gradle, or switch to the gmavenplus plugin (that's what I did), you would dodge the issue because you wouldn't need to rely on eclipse in that case.